# zsh - How can I do automatic resetting of the session on invalid command execution; avoiding "Broken Pipe" message

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I am using oh-my-zsh on iTerm2. Every time an invalid command is executed, zsh shows the "Broken Pipe" message. Please see the screen-shot below:

[image: zsh-broken-pipe-message]

I have to manually reset the session by pressing "command+R" (Macbook) in order to get the prompt back and start using the shell again.

I would want the zsh/iTerm2 to bring back the prompt automatically in case an invalid command is executed.

Is there any setting/configuration I can do in zsh to achieve the desired behavior?

**EDIT:** My iTerm is configured to use zsh instead of login shell.

Comment: It's not clear what (`oh-my-zsh`? `zsh`? iTerm2 itself?) produces that message, or how you are starting `zsh` in the first place (is it your login shell? Do you start it from `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`? Is iTerm2 configured to run `zsh` instead of your login shell?)

Comment: @chepner I edited my question. I was able to find the solution. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some [research](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Trap-Functions), I found the solution.

We can use the zsh's ERROR trap to re-launch the shell in case there is an error in the command or the command exits with error status.

I wrote the following in .zshrc file:

```
TRAPZERR() {
if [[ $? -gt 0 ]];then
     /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --launch_shell
fi
}
```

And it worked !!